# Confused about the action tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I've got an html page with a form set up as follows:

```
<form name="form" action="process.php" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    <br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="pass">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
</form>
```

When I click my submit button, the data is sent to my process.php script, and that's all well and good.

But what I'd like to do is send a JSON string to a PHP script instead, and have that PHP script parse it.
As such I tried the following:

```
<body>
PLEASE ENTER YOUR INFORMATION:
<form name="form" action="">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    <br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="pass">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" onclick="encrypt(this.form, 0)">
</form>
</body>


<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function encrypt(form, key){

    var user = form.user.value;
    var pass = form.pass.value;
    var str = {"username": user, "encrypted_password": pass};
    var JSON_str = JSON.stringify(str);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "process.php", true);
    xhr.send(JSON_str);

}

</script>
```

Yet this doens't do anything. When I click the submit button nothing happens. Even if I could just get process.php to display something when I click the submit button, that would be enormously helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some context? why send as a json string?

Comment: You should look at AJAX calls, you might find it interesting!

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a noob with javascript/php, so I don't have a justification about why sending as a JSON string would be worse/better than just the form data.
I'm only confused about what happens once I post the data to my script.
It seems to me action="process.php" tells the browser to run that script, but posting the JSON string only "sends" the string away.
How can I get it run the php script? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use onclick event then you need to replace submit with button.

```
<input type="button" value="LOGIN" onclick="encrypt(this.form, 0)">
```

and submit form with javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain how I can avoid submitting the form with javascript? I want to send a JSON string to my php script and have it RUN. Right now even if I click on my button, nothing happens. I stay on the same page.

Comment: If you use type="button", your form will not submitted.To submit form usig javascript you need to write code.